# Update SQLite DB in WinDev Mobile 21

Tags: sqlite, windev

I'm trying to update an existent SQLite DB with WinDev Mobile 21. The DB has stored data and I don't want to lose it.

I've updated the Analysis in the project adding a column to a table and now the app can't open it because the structure of the .db file is different from the expected.

First I thought in use the SQL "ATER TABLE" statement and add the new column to the .db file, but I don't know how. So I tried to connect to the old DB before opening, copy the existent data to a temporary Data Source, delete the file, create a new one with the new structure and copy the stored data to it.

This is the code I tried, info function must return the number of records but returns 0. HOpenConnection() and HExecuteSQLQuery() are successful.

```
ProductesTemp is Data Source

HDescribeConnection("Temp","","","/sdcard/Android/data/com.dbases/ficheret.db/ficheret.db","ficheret",hNativeAccessSQLite,hOReadWrite)

IF HOpenConnection("Temp") THEN

IF HExecuteSQLQuery(ProductesTemp,"Temp",hQueryDefault,"SELECT * FROM Productes") THEN

    Info("HRecNum: " + HRecNum(ProductesTemp))

ELSE
    Info("HExecuteSQLQuery Error", HErrorInfo(hErrFullDetails))
END

ELSE
    Info("HOpenConnection Error", HErrorInfo(hErrFullDetails))
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check if HOpenConnection() and HExecuteSQLQuery() are successful.
It should return true if it is. 
Otherwise you should get info by something like that:

```
IF NOT(HOpenConnection("TEMP"))
Info(HErrorInfo(hErrFullDetails))
END
```

What does it say ?

Comment: HOpenConnection() and HExecuteSQLQuery() are successful, Info() prints "HRecNum: 0". I've just updated the code with your suggestion.

Comment: Can you give it a try with HExecuteSQLQuery(ProductesTemp,"Temp",hQueryWithoutCorrection,"SELECT * FROM Productes") ?

Comment: It has no difference